# Riley Riddle #6: Opening act

Tags: riddle

My beginning lives off a small set of skills.
My centre offers rice and raw fish some thrills.
My ending's a letter if it looked like its sound.
You can see me before where the story is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you a

> Proem? Def: a preface or preamble to a book or speech.

My beginning lives off a small set of skills.

> A pro

My centre offers rice and raw fish some thrills.

> Roe: the mass of eggs contained in the ovaries of a female fish or shellfish, typically including the ovaries themselves, especially when ripe and used as food. Used for sushi

My ending's a letter if it looked like it's sound.

> em, which sounds like the letter m.

You can see me before where the story is found.

> It's essentially the preface of a book.

Comment: Congrats! I'm glad someone knows obscure words.

Comment: @flashstorm, it's more like I looked up synonyms to preface...

Comment: Fair. I learnt proem cause I had a big play made against me with it once in Scrabble.

Answer (score 5):

Are you a

> Prologue?

My beginning lives off a small set of skills.

> A PRO can certainly do that, ie. a pro athlete is really great at one sport (usually).

My centre offers rice and raw fish some thrills.

> LOG, as in the fact that sushi looks like a log?

My ending's a letter if it looked like it's sound.

> UE sounds like U.

You can see me before where the story is found.

> A PROLOGUE comes before the story.

Comment: ROT13(Tbbq yhpx svaqvat tbbq nafjref gb gur prager naq raqvat pyhr.)

Comment: Is this not correct? Or do I have the right word but not the correct interpretation?

Comment: Your word is incorrect, and that should be reasonably clear given that two of your answers are such poor fits.

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> Programme?

My beginning lives off a small set of skills.

> PRO - based on El-Guest's answer - professionals rely on a small set of skills in order to make a living.

My centre offers rice and raw fish some thrills.

> GRAM - Gram flour can be used to make fried fish and you would batter the fish with it while it's still raw. Not sure how it can offer rice some thrills though.

My ending's a letter if it looked like it's sound.

> ME - Sounds like M

You can see me before where the story is found.

> Programmes are handed out before theatre shows.

Additionally

> Programme being the answer would also explain the title of the puzzle "Opening Act". Also, the word "centre" from the second clue could be a hint by itself as to how the answer needs to be spelled in order to fall in line with the clues. For example, centre can also be spelled center and programme can also be spelled program, but then you would just have pro and gram.

Comment: ROT13(Lbhe nafjref sbe prager naq raqvat qba'g svg, ohg V guvax lbh pbhyq gryy gung.)